# (Ruby) while loop stops my code from running

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to run the following code (my goal was to make a "game" where i make two objects and have them "fight" each other):

```
#player definition
Player=Struct.new(:health, :dmg)
active_player=Player.new(10, 2)

puts "test"

#monster definition
class Monster
    attr_accessor :health, :damage
    def initialize(health, damage)
        @health=health
        @damage=damage
    end
end
big_spider=Monster.new(4, 1)


player_win=false
monster_win=false

#the fight itself
while (!player_win) or (!monster_win)
    big_spider.health-=active_player.dmg
    active_player.health-=big_spider.damage
    if big_spider.health<=0
        player_win=true
    elsif active_player.health<=0
        monster_win=true
    end
end

#prints out who wins
case monster_win
    when true
        puts "the monster wins"
    when false
        puts "the player wins"
    else
        puts "error"
end

gets.chomp #is there to ensure that the program doesn't exit immediately after execution(yes i have tried removing it)
```

When I try to run that code (from Windows 10 PowerShell) it prints out "test" and then stops as if it was asking for input, however when I try to type anything it doesn't appear on the screen and I can't react with PowerShell in any other way than closing/minimising it (I even try pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> as when exiting irb). I tried running the code in many other ways (through Notepad++, from file explorer, and through cmd.exe), yet i still ran into the same problem. When I comment out the lines from the "the fight itself" comment to the end of the code the program prints out "test",then asks for input and then stops executing. I haven't really found anyone with a similar issue anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That loop spins until BOTH win. With your current code, this is impossible. You want to change it to something like

```
while !player_win && !monster_win
```

Personally, I prefer to write such loops like this:

```
loop do
  break if player_win
  break if monster_win
  ...
end
```